# Can't get Spring Security method authentication to work

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

This might be a long post so I apologize but I've not been able to crack this one. I've managed to set up Spring Security on a test Spring MVC project such that basic http authentication works fine. My next step was to set up method authentication on services so I've followed several tutorials. Unfortunately my methods are not being secured as I can access my test methods as any authorized user regardless of role. I should mention I'm not trying to secure controller methods as I know that requires AspectJ, which I'm not ready for. Here are my config files if they help. Thanks!

Partial log4j output:

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-    instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@23ec1e48: defining beans         [helloController,homeController,testService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#1,org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.memory.InMemoryDaoImpl#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource - @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) found on specific method: public java.lang.String com.arturoaraya.testapp.HelloController.printAdminWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource - Adding security method [CacheKey[com.arturoaraya.testapp.HelloController; public java.lang.String com.arturoaraya.testapp.HelloController.printAdminWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
INFO : org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource - @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasRole('ROLE_USER')) found on specific method: public java.lang.String com.arturoaraya.testapp.HelloController.printWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource - Adding security method [CacheKey[com.arturoaraya.testapp.HelloController; public java.lang.String com.arturoaraya.testapp.HelloController.printWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasRole('ROLE_USER')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Added URL pattern: /welcome*; attributes: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
```

web.xml

```
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">


<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/welcome" />
</http>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.arturoaraya.testapp" />
<context:spring-configured/>
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

UPDATE:

Here is the protected method definition:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public String getAdminMessage() {
    return "Welcome admin user!<br>Here is your secret message:<br><br>BOO!";
}
```

Comment: What is the path to the page that you're trying to secure?

Comment: The page url is /welcome/admin. The page itself is not secured in the security xml file. What I am doing is calling my protected method in the controller method located at this url. The relevant line of code is `model.addAttribute("adminMessage", service.testAdminMethod());` I'll add the method definition above. I hope this helps.